# Are there any implications when using a self-signed certificate only for local encryption on Android?

Tags: android, security, cryptography, certificate, android-keystore

For Android API below 23, we cannot store a `SecretKey` in `Keystore`, so a recommended solution that I found is to use the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` to build a pair of asymmetric keys, which I have to provide a certificate containing an expiration date. Thus, I can use the public key to encrypt and the private key to decrypt my self-generated symmetric key.  My question is: when it expires, I can just generate another pair of private/public keys with a new self-signed certificate and do a re-encryption using the new ones? What are the security implications of doing it?

Comment: why do you want asymmetric crypto here?  i.e. why not just stick with symmetric crypto and keep the key in the keystore

Comment: because for API below 23, the Keystore accepts only asymmetric keys.